# Is there a way to set up an iframe blacklist?

Tags: iis, iframe, clickjacking

I have noticed at least one site that is including my website in an iframe and I am curious about the best way to disallow this type of behavior.

I already included some Javascript that should be able to pick up if a site is framing mine so I can generate a list of sites I want to block. However, there are sites I don't want to disallow iframing from.

Would it be possible through IIS (7) to look at a list of sites, and if a request is coming from a site in that list, to fail somehow or block the request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`X-Frame-Options: deny`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-FRAME-OPTIONS#Frame-Options) HTTP header to prevent anyone from `<iframe>`ing your site. If you want to be able to `<iframe>` your own site but prevent others from doing so, just use
`X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`.

[More reading on `X-Frame-Options` over at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Side note: blacklisting generally doesn't work for security. *Whitelisting* is the right approach.

---

> The Allow-From will only allow a single URI, which means that if I use the Facebook URI it will kill my image uploader, and if I use Sameorigin the image uploader (and any of my own iframes) will work, but it would kill Facebook. Do you know if there is any kind of combination of Allow-From and Sameorigin so that they are both enforced?

[This is not possible given the current spec.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-x-frame-options-01#page-4) You could, however, use 2 different URLs to serve the same content: one for iframing in Facebook (sending `allow-from`) and one for your own iframes (sending `sameorigin`). Not great, but better than nothing.

Comment: I've tried setting the X-Frame-Options to 'deny', but it shuts off all iframes (which is expected). I have Facebook pages that iframe pages on my site that I need to keep available. That setting also messes with my image uploader script which does some strange iframe actions.

Comment: I agree with the Whitelisting approach, though. That might be a better way to go about this, if possible.

Comment: Okay, so use `allow-from: <facebook URI>`.

Comment: The Allow-From will only allow a single URI, which means that if I use the Facebook URI it will kill my image uploader, and if I use Sameorigin the image uploader (and any of my own iframes) will work, but it would kill Facebook. Do you know if there is any kind of combination of Allow-From and Sameorigin so that they are both enforced?

Comment: I think this is not possible given the current spec. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-x-frame-options-01#page-4 You could, however, use 2 different URLs to serve the same content. One for iframing in Facebook (sending `allow-from`) and one for your own iframes (sending `sameorigin`). Not great, but better than nothing.

Comment: I think that answers my question pretty well. I believe what I will do is use my Javascript logging and set request filtering through IIS. There doesn't seem to be a great way to handle this automatically but should work for me. Thanks for your help. That link is a great resource.